# Resources deleted from Azure portal shows as still available when using "msbot clone services" bot-builder-tools command

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, botframework

We are trying to create services using "msbot clone services" bot-builder-tools command.

After successfully running it once, deleted resource group using Azure portal and retried the same command again. Got error that bot already exists and it also gave command to delete the resource using "az bot delete --name   --group-name  --no-wait" command. On running this new command, it rightly reported that resource doesn't exist.

Question is why msbot clone services report that resource exists, which infact has been deleted.

[image: Click to view image]

Comment: Did it say exactly _which_ resource still exists? I would imagine there's some more specific detail from the command that you could copy/paste here...???

Comment: Hi Drew, Added image for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete `TransactionalBot.bot`, locally. It's saying that the `.bot` file exists, not an Azure Resource.

Alternatively, you can change the `--name` argument to something other than `TransactionalBot`

Comment: You have a point, but look at the arrow in the image attached. Its misleading that a command to delete resource using az command is displayed. It gives an impression that a resource in Azure needs to be deleted.

Comment: I agree. It does that by default any time `msbot clone services` fails, so that if it created resources anywhere in the process, you can delete them easily. But you're right, it's confusing if it says it right away like that. If my answer solved this for you, mind marking it "answered" so I can clear it off my support tracker?